# What do the hash marks (#) mean in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I rather new to Vue, and cannot figure out exactly what the hash symbol `#` (i.e. `#item.active`) means in Vue.

As the hash symbol is a difficult term to search on the web!

```html
<template #item.active="{ value }">
  <div :aria-label="String(value)" class="text-center">
    <v-icon v-if="value === null">mdi-minus</v-icon>
    <v-icon v-else color="red">mdi-close</v-icon>
  </div>
</template>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It's shorthand for the [`v-slot`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot) attribute.

Comment: Really? Thanks Edric!

Comment: "Googling a # isn't an easy thing to do." I agree, thanks for the question !

Comment: Drop me an upvote then!

Comment: "Googling a # isn't an easy thing to do" -> Googling for this was really a nightmare actually. Even after reading this, I still can't find where the docs mention this, apart from saying "shorthand: #" next to [v-slot](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot)... Many thanks for asking the answer and wording it in such a way that it was searchable

Comment: Yeah the vue docs kinda suck really.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `#` symbol is a shorthand for the [`v-slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot) attribute, as hinted by the usage of `<template>` (which `v-slot` only allows to be used on, as well as components) in your code.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will mark you as the answer. 
Of course now that i know what to google i find it everywhere!