# How add class to "template" tag in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I need to know how can I add a class to "template" tag in vue.

```
<template 
  #popover
  class: templateClass // Is it possible to add a class in here?
>
  <router-link
    v-close-popover
    to="/somewhere"
  >
    Go to the page
  </router-link>
</template>
```

Comment: I don't know the syntax you're using, but if `#popover` results in `id="popover"`, then setting CSS class is probably as easy as `.templateClass`.

Comment: @connexo the point is class won't be added to the template. There's no class attribute in element tab in browser

Comment: Check what you get with this: `<template #foo .bar><span>Hello world</span></template>`.

Comment: `<template>` isn't a real DOM element so you can't add a class to it. The component with that slot should accept the class as a prop and add it to the appropriate element within it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't bind any classes to the template tag as the template tag itself does not render an element for itself.
What you're trying to achieve is not possible despite the comments made on the contrary.
There's a reason why Vue2 needs a root element for it's components.
Adding `#templateRef` to the template-tag is just a shorthand for v-slot (see [What do the hash marks (#) mean in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731076/what-do-the-hash-marks-mean-in-vue)) and does basically nothing for you in this case.